# How do I create a Json file in Asp.net MVC

Tags: jquery

I was studying a Jquery tutorial and it tells me to make a Json file...
But I didnt find anything with that extension in Visual Studio....
How do I create a .json file with Visual Studio?

Comment: Simplest way is to create a Text file and then rename it in the Solution Explorer

Comment: I would also add that the user can take the json file he/she created from the jQuery tutorial and just add it to the project by dragging it to the solution explorer.